# Closed linear span of a bounde sequence in X reflexive

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a reflexive normed space and $\{y_n\}_n$ is a bounded sequence in $X$. 
Let $Y$ be the closed linear span of the $y_n$.

Is $Y$ **separable** and/or **reflexive** - if yes/not **why**?

Comment: Do you know what it means that a space is separable? Do you know some theorem about reflexivity of subspaces of a reflexive space?

Comment: Yes - Separable means that it containts a countable dense subset. And yes I know some theorem but I have not one in mind that could help me. Maybe you have one?

Comment: Okay. So start with the hypothesis that $Y$ is separable. Can you think of a good candidate of a countable dense subset? Regarding reflexivity, what theorem do you know?

Comment: what about $D_n=\{y_i \vert \sum_i^n\lambda_iy_i\leq c\}$ where $c>0$ is a constant as a countable dense subset in $Y$? (I'm sorry I'm quite novice in this field) 
Regarding reflexivity I have that _a reflexive normed vector space is necessary complete_ And a theorem states that : _$X$ a banach space is reflexive if and only if its dual space $X^*$ is reflexive._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are theorems:

1. If $E$ is reflexive, then $E$ isva Banach Space.
2. If $E$ is reflexive, any closed subspace of $E$ is also reflexive.

So $Y$ is reflexive.

As for separability, we can set 
$$L_0 = \left\{ y:y = \sum_1^k q_iy_i, \text{ where $q_i$  is  rational} \right\} ,$$ 
$$ L = \left\{ y:y = \sum_1^k r_iy_i,\text{ where $r_i$ is real}\right \}. $$

$L_0$ is dense in $L$, $L_0$ is countable, $L$ is dense in $Y$, so $Y$ is separable.

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot !